# D3 Slider with ordinal scale Error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using sample example of D3 with slider.

http://codepen.io/DougManuel/full/avRyMg

https://github.com/MasterMaps/d3-slider

I clanged code **Slider with ordinal scales (categories)**  to

```
essai = d3.slider().scale(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["2001", "2002", "Winter-2003", "2004-2005"]).rangePoints([0, 1], 0.5)).axis(d3.svg.axis()).snap(true).value("2001"); d3.select('#slider12').call(essai);
```

This code is not working. Please give me suggestion how i can resolved this issue.

Comment: What happens? That code works fine for me: http://codepen.io/jeznagcozero/pen/EmVVrO

Comment: Please check code section Slider with ordinal scales (categories). Slider does not move.

Comment: It seems to be a bug with having numbers as the category. It worked fine if I put "Year 2001" instead of "2001".     

essai = d3.slider().scale(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["Year 2001", "Year 2002", "Winter-2003", "Year 2004-2005"]).rangePoints([0, 1], 0.5)).axis(d3.svg.axis()).snap(true).value("Year 2001");

You could add info here:
https://github.com/MasterMaps/d3-slider/issues/11